# SourceTree lost all branches and commits

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

A random thing happened on SourceTree, working fine yesterday but loaded it up this morning to do some more work and everything has disappeared. SourceTree now wants me to commit everything again as if it was the first commit.

Strangely, running git log --all in the terminal does show all the commits. I am getting this when trying to git log normally.

```
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'
```

Is there any way to repair this so I can see all my branches and commits again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who has experienced this problem here is how I have fixed it from piecing together various other posts.

First you need to get your last commit, adding the --all worked for me otherwise I'd get "fatal: bad HEAD" error.

```
git reflog --all
```

Then you need to check to make sure you have a HEAD file. If not I recreated one by doing the following:

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

Once this has been done you should be able to hard reset to the most recent commit using:

```
git reset --hard 73b9363
```

Replace the commit id after --hard for the commit which is the newest from your git reflog --all.